# jQuery - text-decoration underline toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm trying to write a text-decoration toggle.

When I clicked the link, the link should be underlined and if I clicked it a second time the link shouldn't be underlined. It also should toggle if e.g the first link was clicked once, then e.g the third one is clicked, the first link shouldn't be underlined etc.

**jQuery Code:**

```
 $(".underlinetoggle").click(function () {
     if($(".underlinetoggle").css('text-decoration', 'none')) {
         $(".underlinetoggle").css('text-decoration', 'underline');
     }
     else if($(".underlinetoggle").css('text-decoration', 'underline')){
         $(".underlinetoggle").css('text-decoration', 'none');
     }
 });
```

**HTML:**

```
<a class="underlinetoggle-one">Link to toggle 1</a>
<a class="underlinetoggle-two">Link to toggle 2</a>
<a class="underlinetoggle-three">Link to toggle 3</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.underlinetoggle {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: orange;
}
```

Sorry if I done a quite hard mistake, because I'm new to jQuery/JavaScript.
I'll hope there's a way to do this. Thanks for taking the time to answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a bit of `css` for this like bellow

```
.underline{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

And this much script using starts with selector

```
$("a[class^='underlinetoggle']").click(function () {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('underline');
  $(this).toggleClass('underline');
});
```

[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/28/)

Comment: But the problem with it, the default link has no text-decoration.

Comment: @LukasRené if you'll see in my demo, in starting there is no underline.

Comment: I'll gonna test it now.

Comment: Perfect, it works, thanks man ! //EDIT: The problem is, I really need an IF clause, because i've got more links and it should switch off the underline when I click on an other link,

Comment: @LukasRené then also there is no need of `if` see updated answer & demo.

Comment: Okey, thank you ! (btw it's 18 not 17 in the link :-))

Comment: Thx anyways, gonna test it on my project now.

Comment: @LukasRené Ok check it & if it works accept the answer, & if doesn't let me know.

Comment: Oh, I failed to change sth. in my HTML Code in my question. Every link got an other class. E.g: toggle-one ... toggle-ten .. Sorry bout that

Comment: @LukasRené just one suggestion, I appreciate that you din't paste the whole code, and tried to replicate your problem in simple, but you forgot many aspects of it, So be clear before you ask question.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll promise to do this in futer. I'm sorry but in my timezone its 06 AM and I hadn't slept until now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this is working as you want. please like if it's what you want.

```
$(".anchorToggle").click(function () {
    if($(this).css('text-decoration')=="none"){
        $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    }
    else
        $(this).css('text-decoration', 'none');
});
```

see fsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/gaurav22031987/2c5vbq1q/7/

Comment: change condition to  if ($(this).css('text-decoration').indexOf("none") > -1)  see jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/2c5vbq1q/12/